# I want to get data by start date, start time and end date, end time

Tags: c#

I have created an application and I am getting data from the .csv file using the link label option and I want to get data by start date, start time and end date, end time.

I tried only using one date, start time, and end time like
24/6/2019 10:00:00 AM to 23:00:00 PM

```
    private Task<List<Tag>> SearchCSV()
    {
        return Task.Run<List<Tag>>(() => {
        var t = new List<Tag>();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath) || !File.Exists(filePath))
            return new List<Tag>();
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string[] row = Regex.Split(sr.ReadLine(), ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");

                    if (!DateTime.TryParse(row[0] as string, out DateTime date))
                        continue;
                    DateTime.TryParse(row[1] as string, out DateTime time);
                    DateTime dateTime = date.Add(new TimeSpan(time.Hour, time.Minute, time.Second));
                        if (dateTime >= startDate && dateTime <= endDate) { }
                       // t.Add(new Tag(dateTime, decimal.TryParse(row[selectedTankIndex + 2], out decimal tagValue) ? tagValue : 0));
                    }
                }
            }
            return t;
        });
    }
```

I want data to fetch like 24/6/2019 10:00:00 AM to 7/8/2019 23:00:00 PM.

How can I do it, please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? The question is unclear to me. Also, just as a side note, you may want to consider using a CSV library for parsing your file.  [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) for example.  You can create a class to represent the rows and parse directly into the class object.

Comment: in the above code there some issue sir i made it for another project using one tank detail and one date and start time and end time so i don't know how to change according like 24/6/2019 10:00:00 AM to 7/8/2019 23:00:00 PM

Comment: visualbasic has a csv parser, no idea why its not in csharp but you can reference it just fine.  I use it all the time:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: and i agree the question is unclear.   Please state what you want to happen and what actually is happening.

Comment: In order to be able to help you we need to understand the problem better, what is working, what isn't working, etc.  Provide a sample of the CSV data (with column headers if you have them). Give us an idea of the size your CSV file - that is is it 100's of rows, 1000's, 1,000,000's etc. Please edit the question to provide this information.

Answer (score 0):

If you can I would suggest you use the TextFieldParser class.  Its in the VB namespace but can still be referenced from C#, it will remove the need for the possibly buggy and hard to read regex:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
```

...

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (var sr = new TextFieldParser(fileStream))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] row = sr.ReadFields();
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(row[0] as string, out DateTime date))
                continue;
            DateTime.TryParse(row[1] , out DateTime time);

                //etc
        }
    }
}
```

Also if your date can be in different formats you can use TryParseExact which can take several different formats:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(row[0], new []{"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", "d/m/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", "d/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", "dd/m/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,out var result);
```